# Unable to Use Custom Component in Main Page - Typescript Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-component

I am trying to make a custom Alert component:

```
type Severity = "error" | "success" | "info" | "warning" | undefined;

export default function CustomAlert(severity: Severity, text: string){
    return(
    <Alert style={{width:'50%'}} severity={severity}> {text}</Alert>)
}
```

but I am unable to use it in my main page's function:

```
  function StatusMessage(){
        if (errorMessage.includes(`Couldn't find user`)){
          return (
            <div>
            <CustomAlert severity='error' text='User Not Found'></CustomAlert>
            </div>
              )
  }
```

The custom alert gives me this error:

```
Type '{ severity: string; text: string; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & "success") | (IntrinsicAttributes & "info") | (IntrinsicAttributes & "warning") | (IntrinsicAttributes & "error")'.
  Type '{ severity: string; text: string; }' is not assignable to type '"error"'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional components receive *one* parameter: `props`. You can use the whole object or destructure it, but you can't pass more than one.

```js
function CustomAlert({severity: Severity, text: string})
```

```js
function CustomAlert(props: {severity: Severity, text: string})
```